# Anyone feel like a Gematria numeric challenge in EXCEL VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

To explain: I’m in EXCEL and need a genius formula in VBA, where each letter in the alphabet (except j) is given a SPECIFIC numeric value (as listed below), so that as you type LETTERS in one cell, the SUM OF THE NUMERIC VALUES appear in the cell next to it.

```
a=1     b=2     c=600   d=4     e=5     f=500   g=3   h=8    i=10
k=20    l=30    m=40    n=50    o=70    p=80    q=9   r=100  s=200
t=300   u=400   v=200   w=800   x=60    y=700   z=7
```

(Note: It should also apply to CAPS and a space should count zero)

e.g: If I type the words `lady asks help` in cell A1, the value `1279` should appear in cell B1 
(Seeing that l=30, a=1, d=4, y=700, a=1, s=200, k=20, s=200, h=8, e=5, l=30, p=80)

The same formula should apply to the rest of Columns A and B.
In case it’s important, I need it for Greek Gematria. As I type “abc” on the keyboard, the Greek letters “αβχ” appear on the screen (by use of the Tyndale House keyboard code). Each Greek letter has a set numeric value, confirming numeric patterns found in Greek Bible Texts.
I’ve found fixed programs using Greek Gematria (e.g. DAVAR4), but none are editable text and I don’t know how to get into their ‘brains’ to transfer it to EXCEL. Frankly, I’m really clueless when it comes to programming and don’t even know if what I’m asking is possible. Local programmers referred me to Stack Overflow, so ANY help or directive would be much appreciated! 
I looked at this question & answer, asked Jul 7 '14 by data_garden, but alas, I’m a dummy!
Please say if any more info is needed. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're in luck. There are votes for this to be closed as you've made no apparent effort to write the code yourself. I've written something similar myself recently so all that was needed was to replace the array with your scoring system and it is below:

```
Function gem(txt As String) As Long
    gem = 0
    Dim i As Long, c As Integer
    Dim arr()
    arr = Array(0, 1, 2, 600, 4, 5, 500, 3, 8, 10, 0, 20, 30, 40, 50, 70, 80, 9, 100, 200, 300, 400, 200, 800, 60, 700, 7)
    For i = 1 To Len(txt)
        c = Asc(Mid(UCase(txt), i, 1)) - 64
        If c > 0 And c <= 26 Then gem = gem + arr(c)
    Next
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks a million CLR!

Comment: Sorry Guys, I probably should have mentioned I've never written code or done programming in my life! My previous question I just Copied & pasted the code without understanding the language (I thought ByVal meant it's the person who wrote the code -lol!) Sorry for picking your brains for a shortcut. I'll watch tutorials and who knows, maybe one day I'll be able  to contribute to your site by answering a question! (ha-ha) CLR, thanks again for redeeming AND answering my question and shrivallabha.redij for editing my format. OK. Happy coding and feel free to delete this overlong message!